# Need to overwrite cells in a column without overwriting the other cells in the same column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to overwrite the SERIALNUMBER to 'NONE' only if the DESCRIPTION contains 'fuel'.

```
cols = ['DESCRIPTION', 'SERIALNUMBER']
data = [['vehicle; truck', '123456'],
        ['fuel; truck', 'nan'],
        ['vehicle; car', '789456'],
        ['fuel; car', 'nan'],
        ['vehicle; semi', '653123'],
        ['fuel; semi', 'nan']
       ]
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols)

     DESCRIPTION     SERIALNUMBER
0    vehicle; truck   123456
1    fuel; truck       nan
2    vehicle; car     789456
3    fuel; car         nan
4    vehicle; semi    653123
5    fuel; semi        nan
```

I tried using the `df.replace`, but it replaces the serial numbers that are currently there with 0.

```
c1 = df['DESCRIPTION'].str.contains('fuel;')
df['SERIALNUMBER'].replace(c1, value='NONE', inplace=True)
```

What I end up with is

```
DESCRIPTION     SERIALNUMBER
0    vehicle; truck   0
1    fuel; truck       NONE
2    vehicle; car     0
3    fuel; car         NONE
4    vehicle; semi    0
5    fuel; semi        NONE
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. I get expected output.

Comment: @harvpan: well locally I see no change *at all*, it just stays `nan`, not `NONE`.

Comment: @DeAnnaMartinez: are you sure you did not set the `'SERIALNUMBER'` to an `int` type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can usee the `df['DESCRIPTION']` here as a filter to set the corresponding `'SERIALNUMBER'` column to `None` (or something else):

```
df.loc[df['DESCRIPTION'].str.contains('fuel;'), 'SERIALNUMBER'] = None
```

or for a string `'NONE'`:

```
df.loc[df['DESCRIPTION'].str.contains('fuel;'), 'SERIALNUMBER'] = 'NONE'
```

This will give us for the former:

```
      DESCRIPTION SERIALNUMBER
0  vehicle; truck       123456
1     fuel; truck         None
2    vehicle; car       789456
3       fuel; car         None
4   vehicle; semi       653123
5      fuel; semi         None
```

or for the latter:

```
>>> df
      DESCRIPTION SERIALNUMBER
0  vehicle; truck       123456
1     fuel; truck         NONE
2    vehicle; car       789456
3       fuel; car         NONE
4   vehicle; semi       653123
5      fuel; semi         NONE
```

Comment: this was just an example dataframe. but the NONE worked on my real df i'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
mask = ['fuel' in x for x in df.DESCRIPTION]
df.loc[mask, 'SERIALNUMBER'] = None
```

Output

```
      DESCRIPTION SERIALNUMBER
0  vehicle; truck       123456
1     fuel; truck         None
2    vehicle; car       789456
3       fuel; car         None
4   vehicle; semi       653123
5      fuel; semi         None
```